# get displayname from samaccountname

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am looking for a way to get the `displayname` of a user from their `samaccountame`.

```
$username = Read-host 'Username'
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -like $($name.DisplayName)$username}
```

I want to put the `displayname` into a variable called `$user`

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Get-ADUser $username | select -expand name`

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = Read-host 'Username'
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$username'" |select name
```